# How to hard code images in c# using if/else statements

Tags: c#, html

I'm currently making a website and I'm in need of some help. I have 10 boxes that need to be with different images and wanted to do that using an If/else statement.

```
a href="@Url.Action("View","Entry", new { id = i })" target="_blank"><img class="test" src="~/Content/pictures/test.jpg" alt="" style="width:30%;height:25%;"/>
```

This is how i implemented the boxes, with a for loop above.
I now want to make them each have a different image but i get an error using my if statement :

```
if (i == 1)//where i is the ID of the image
                {
                    i["src"] = ("~/Content/pictures/test.jpg");
                }
```

I get an error using this because i is an int and it needs a string. Tried converting i to a string but that didn't help out eighter.
This might not be the right way to do it, so please share your opinions on this.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you clarify: if `i` is an `int`, what is `i["src"]` meant to be? I'm confused; is that actually meant to be an `<img>` element or similar?

Comment: You can't use the same name `i` to declare multiple variables. Also consider using a `switch` statement instead of 10x `if`

Comment: I is the int i use in my for loop for the buttons. the i['src'] is a solution i saw but didn't work for me sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kinda sounds like what you actually want here could be as simple as:

```
<img class="test" src="@(imagePaths[i])" ...
```

where `imagePaths` is a `string[]` of the desired paths (assuming 0-based). You could wrap it up in a function, of course:

```
@functions
{
    public string GetImagePath(int index) {
       switch(index) {
          case 1: return "whatever.png";
          case 2: return "something.png";
          default: return "oops.png";
       }
    }
}
...
<img class="test" src="@GetImagePath(i)" ...
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I need something that would check the ID of the image (1-16) and replace it depending on that ID.